# How to check if multiple Lua tables contain common values?

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have a table of tables such as:

```lua
local someTable = {
      idsA = {1, 2, 3, 4},
      idsB = {4, 5, 6, 7},
      idsC = {4, 8, 9, 10}
    }
```

And need to check if there is a common value that exists in all of the sub-tables (in that case - `4`).

Comment: what have you tried? this is not a coding service.
you'll have to iterate over your table and compare each entry. it's also importan what you want to do. do you just want to know if there are common IDs or do you want to know which IDs are common or in which tables they are...

Comment: You realize that's not correct Lua syntax, right?

Comment: In the example you give, all three tables happen to have [sequences](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.7) and no other keys. Is that a structural requirement; something that can be relied on?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are essentially intersecting any number of tables together. I'm sure there are libraries to do it, but here is a naive implementation:

```
local idTables = {
  ["idsA"] = {1, 2, 3, 4},
  ["idsB"] = {4, 5, 6, 7},
  ["idsC"] = {4, 8, 9, 10}
}

local intersection = {}
local firstTable = true
for key, tbl in pairs(idTables) do
  -- If this is the first table we are looking at, populate
  -- our intersection table as a map, mapping every ID that appears to a flag.
  -- Note that the choice of flag being a bool is somewhat arbitrary
  if firstTable then
    for _, v in ipairs(tbl) do
      intersection[v] = true
    end
    firstTable = false
  else
    -- Otherwise, we already have a table to intersect against, so for every 
    -- ID in our intersection map, lets check this next table, to see if 
    -- every element of this next table against our intersection map
    for knownId,_ in pairs(intersection) do
      local newTableHasKnownId = false
      for _,id in ipairs(tbl) do
        if id == knownId then
          -- This new table of IDs we're iterating does have the current ID of
          -- the intersection table we're looking at. We can flag it as such, and stop
          -- looking for that known ID
          newTableHasKnownId = true
          break
        end
      end
      -- Drop the 'known' ID from the intersection map if it wasn't in the table
      -- we just iterated.
      if not newTableHasKnownId then
        intersection[knownId] = nil
      end
    end
   end
end

print('intersection results:')
for key,_ in pairs(intersection) do
  print(key)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a straightforward intersection to find all common indexes:

```
t={a={1,2,3},
   b={2,6},
   c={2,4,5}}

function intersect(m,n)
 local r={}
 for x in all(m) do
  for y in all(n) do
   if (x==y) then
    add(r,x)
    break
   end
  end
 end
 return r
end

function common_idx(t)
 local r=nil
 for k,v in pairs(t) do
  if not r then
   r=intersect(v,v)
  else
   r=intersect(r,v)
  end
 end
 return r
end

-- 2
for k,v in pairs(common_idx(t)) do
 print(v)
end
```